# What is the Russian word for "blending stump" (artist's tool)?

Tags: словарь, терминология

There is a [tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortillon) used by artists called *blending stump* (in English) or *tortillon* (in French). But I cannot find the word for it in Russian. This is how they (tools) look like:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called Растушка, растушовка/растушёвка.

> blending stump
> Искусство: растушка

Универсальный англо-русский словарь. Академик.ру. 2011.

from th verb растушевывать.

> РАСТУШКА — и (чаще) РАСТУШОВКА, растушовки, жен. (спец.). 1. только ед. Действие по гл. растушевать растушевывать. 2. Скрученная из бумаги или другого мягкого материала заостренная палочка для тушовки (живоп. спец.). Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков.… …   Толковый словарь Ушакова
>
> Растушёвка – это в общем-то частный случай штриховки. После нанесения штрихов, используя свойства графита карандаша и свой инструмент для растушевки (растушку) , штрихи как бы размазывают до получения однородного тона.
> Держать растушку при работе надо под углом и ни в коем случае не перпендикулярно плоскости листа. Лучше всего аналогом бумажной (замшевой) скрученной растушки будет служить кусок натуральной винной пробки заточенной на конус или клином с тонким рабочим концом. Также в качестве растушки можно использовать кусочек ватки, ватную палочку, кусок мягкой бумаги, свернутый на конус и т. п.

Comment: I believe the modern spelling is _растушёвка_

Comment: +1 **растушёвка** — [грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%88%D1%91%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x)

Comment: Why you are using two variants: растушЁвка и растушОвка. They are all correct?

Comment: I gave you three, which I found in different dictionaries. The spelling was different  earlier, they wrote " о ". Modern spelling is "ё", "растушка" is still used. When you write, you can use two. You can find the old spelling in older books. Just for you to know they all mean the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is very special tool most people does not know what it is or how it is called and i think in different regions it can be called differently. But me and everybody i know call it `растушка`. And i think there is not much difference in these words `растушка` and `растушовка`.